# C++ template constructor like these

Tags: c++

How could i define a constructor for my class for these constructor calls:

```
MyClass<std::list<int>, int> myClass1;
 MyClass<std::deque<std::string>, std::string> myClass2;
 MyClass<std::vector<char>, char> myClass3;
```

I know if it would be:

```
MyClass<int> myClass1;
```

I would do like:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass{
//...
};
```

But how could i add entire collections with templates?

Comment: Is the second type always going to be the same as the type contained within the container?

Comment: `template <typename Container, typename Element> class MyClass {...};` What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: @sfrabbit Yes i mean that.

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi: You might want to investigate template template parameters - it's not entirely clear to me what you're after, but they may be worth a look.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz don't suggest OP to use template template parameters for this. Each standard container has a very different set of template parameters, so its very difficult to hold them though a template template parameter. Thats why that containers provides that informtation though traits.

Comment: @Manu343726 So you mean i would just have to define an individual constructor for each of vector, list, etc?

Comment: I think you are missunderstanding something here. You are talking about template parametrization and template instantation, or the definition of the constructor for your class? Are very different things.

Comment: The language of your question seems like by *"constructor calls"* you mean *"Template instantations"*.

Comment: Well, yes i guess so. Sorry for the misunderstood.

Comment: Well, what im trying to do is deifne one single constructor that could be used for each of the template instantations i gave you in the example. And i would like to have one single private container to be the exactly same container on the template instantations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you asked for, you can simply add another template parameter:

```
template <typename Cont, typename T>
class SetSequence {
  //...
};
```

It doesn't matter that it needs to take a container. The container types are just as valid as template arguments as `int` is.

If the `T` argument is always going to be the value type of `Cont`, you can simplify this by having only a single template parameter. Then you can use `Cont::value_type` to refer to the type of its elements.

Comment: And how could i use later on that "Cont" param? I mean i would like to use push_back etc... How could i define a real container from that abstract thing?

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi As you would expect: `Cont container;`

Answer (score 1):

Try with an optional template parameter:

```
template<typename T , typename VALUE_TYPE = typename T::value_type>
struct SetSecuence
{
  ...
};
```

However, you could simply store the value type of the containers as a member typedef:

```
template<typename T>
struct SetSecuence
{
  using value_type = typename T::value_type;
};
```

This works, as you can see:

```
using secuence_type_1 = SetSecuence<std::vector<int>>;
using secuence_type_2 = SetSecuence<std::list<bool>>;

secuence_type_1 secuence;
typename secuence_type_1::value_type an_element_of_that_secuence;
```